# PHP code to make only one customer that can login in my site with the same username and password

Tags: php, session

I want ask about Session in PHP. I have case to make only one customer / one login that can login in my site with the same username and password. This is to avoid customer to use one ID with multiple persons which is against the license agreement.

Can it be handled with PHP Session?

Thank you.

Comment: Not with sessions, but some persistent storage, like DB. Create another table which maintains `user_id <-> session_id` association and if it doesn't match the current `session_id` - log off the user.

Comment: No, it can't be handled by session, because every session is "per connection", not "per user".

Comment: You may want to update the user login in the DB

Comment: @zerkms what if the user doesnt logout and just closes the window. The session id would still stay in the db and prevent others from logging.

Comment: @Abhishek Saha: when you authenticate - that table is updated with the most actual `session_id` (I expected that it's obvious so not stated it explicitly)

Comment: @zerkms - My apology if i am wrong here. What is said is correct. That it gets updated. But wont it get updated only after verifying that there is no user logged in ?

Comment: @Abhishek Saha: you don't check if anyone else is logged in. You: 1. On authentication update the `session_id` for a given user. 2. On every subsequent request you check if the `session_id` matches the current `session_id`. In case it does not - you log out the current user. Additionally one may put ip address to the session and check it as well, to prevent users from sharing their `session_id`s

Comment: @zerkms : Is there any other way other than using a database?

Comment: @benz: as I mentioned - you can use any shared storage. Which sessions are not.